# Paragraph has overflow in a Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My paragraph text gets overlap when too many words are in there.

Here is my code:

```
<a class="dropdown-item content btnOpen">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 p-1">
            <img id="notif_image" class="notif_image" src="sample.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <h6>This the the title</h6>
            <div style="max-width: 500px; display:inline-block">
                <p style="word-wrap: break-word;"><small>flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex</small></p>
            </div>
            <p><small><em>this is a sample time</em></small></p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div></a>
```

And this the output:

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You omitted the most crucial part of your code. It's a Bootstrap-Dropdown.

The class `.dropdown-item` is getting `white-space: nowrap;`. That's why the overflow happens. You have to overwrite that behaviour. For example with a custom class: `.custom-dropdown-menu .dropdown-item { white-space: normal; }`

```css
.custom-dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown">

  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>

  <div class="dropdown-menu custom-dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item content btnOpen">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2 p-1">
            <img id="notif_image" class="notif_image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/30/48/48">
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <h6>This the the title</h6>
            <div>
              <p><small>flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex  flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex  flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex</small></p>
            </div>
            <p><small><em>this is a sample time</em></small></p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="dropdown-item content btnOpen">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2 p-1">
            <img id="notif_image" class="notif_image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/32/48/48">
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <h6>This the the title</h6>
            <div>
              <p><small>flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex flex</small></p>
            </div>
            <p><small><em>this is a sample time</em></small></p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```